# How to change the innerHTML of various divs when clicking on various buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, innerhtml

In my web-page I have various buttons (in the class `.addbutton`). When the first of these is clicked, a `<div>` appears with a drop-down, from which the user can select any of 2 options (`#p1`, `#p2), which vary depending on which button was clicked.

When each of these options is clicked, I want it to appear in the `<div>` that corresponds with the initial `.addbutton` that was clicked. (e.g if the first `.addbutton` is clicked (`#bradd`) I want the options selected in the first div (`#bdiv`))I managed to do this so that they always appear in the `#bdiv`, no matter what `.addbutton` was clicked, but I can't work out how to make each appear in the corresponding one.
JS to set the innerHTML of the 2 options

```
    document.getElementById("bradd").onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Cereal"
      document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "Juice"
    }

    document.getElementById("mmadd").onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "2x small fruit"
      document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "Big fruit"
    }
```

JS to change the innerHTML of the first div (#bdiv)

```
      document.getElementById("p1").onclick = function() {
        var newItem = document.createElement("div")
        newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML document.getElementById("bdiv").appendChild(newItem)
      }
      document.getElementById("p2").onclick = function() {
        var newItem = document.createElement("div")
        newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML
        document.getElementById("bdiv").appendChild(newItem)
      }
```

My HTML:

```
    <h1>Meal Plan Customizer</h1>
    <div id="list">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <p>Breakfast:</p>
      <button class="addbutton" id="bradd">+</button>
      <div id="bdiv"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <p>Mid-Morning:</p>
      <button class="addbutton" id="mmadd">+</button>
      <div id="mdiv"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox">

          <div id="dropdownList">
            <p id="p1">Option1</p><br><br>
            <p id="p2">Option2</p><br><br>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: is it really important to leave such a confusing code of a hundred lines to explain your question? please keep it brief and concise as is often repeated here and recommended here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You also have syntax errors in your example. As @MisterJojo says, please create an *minimal reproducible* example with the smallest amount of code required to recreate the problem (including the CSS if it is relevant). This way we will be able to see the problem more clearly and might be able to help.

Comment: KISS Follow this method while you are asking a question

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work.
Please check this:
https://jsfiddle.net/oliverdev/3wsfgov1/

If your code is not working, it is because Javascript code is loaded before loading the HTML.
You can modify the Javascript code like this:

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
  document.getElementById("bradd").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Cereal"
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "Juice"
  }

  document.getElementById("mmadd").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "2x small fruit"
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "Big fruit"
  }
}
```

It will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You are making this far more complicated and repetitive than necessary.

By storing your data in a structured object and using classes for the content elements you can make generic event listeners for all of this

Following is by no means complete but will give you a good idea how to approach something like this

```js
var data = {
  bradd: {
    p1: "Cereal",
    p2: "Juice"
  },
  mmadd: {
    p1: "2x small fruit",
    p2: "Big fruit"
  }
}

var selectedButton = null;


var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#dropdownList p');

for (let p of opts) {
  p.addEventListener('click', updateContent)
}
// generic event handler for all the options
function updateContent() {
  const content = selectedButton.closest('.item').querySelector('.content')
  content.innerHTML = this.innerHTML
  togglePopup()
}

document.querySelector('#xbutton').addEventListener('click', togglePopup)


// generic event handler for all buttons
function addButtonClicked() {
  selectedButton = this;// store selected for use when option selected
  var wantedData = data[selectedButton.id];
  for (let p of opts) {
    p.innerHTML = wantedData[p.id]
  }
  togglePopup();
}
for (let btn of document.getElementsByClassName("addbutton")) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", addButtonClicked)
}

function togglePopup() {
  var popStyle = document.getElementById("addPopUp").style;
  popStyle.display = popStyle.display === "block" ? 'none' : 'block'
}
```

```css
#addPopUp {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<h1>Meal Plan Customizer</h1>
<div id="list">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Breakfast:</p>
    <button class="addbutton" id="bradd">+</button>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Mid-Morning:</p>
    <button class="addbutton" id="mmadd">+</button>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="addPopUp">
  <h3 id="h3">Select what you would like to add:</h3>
  <span id="xbutton"><strong>&times;</strong></span>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <div id="dropdownList">
      <p id="p1">Option1</p>
      <p id="p2">Option2</p>
      <!-- <p id="p3">Option3</p><br><br>
      <p id="p4">Option4</p>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```